# Amazon AWS returns 0 for all prices

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I'm using the Amazon aws api for pulling out data from Amazon. I want to include price which should be working since you can see from my output includes the "offers" section. But for some reason, no matter what product I search, the price ends up being 0. What gives?

```
ASIN: "B00I2ZBT1Y", DetailPageURL: "http://www.amazon.com/AngryGamez-

WorldCraft/dp/B00…5%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3DB00I2ZBT1Y", ItemLinks: Object, SmallImage: Object, MediumImage: Object…}
ASIN: "B00I2ZBT1Y"
DetailPageURL: "http://www.amazon.com/AngryGamez-WorldCraft/dp/B00I2ZBT1Y%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAI4JZRRS4PA7GCFZQ%26tag%3Dthegeepro-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3DB00I2ZBT1Y"
ImageSets: Object
ItemAttributes: Object
ItemLinks: Object
LargeImage: Object
MediumImage: Object
OfferSummary: Object
LowestNewPrice: Object
TotalCollectible: "0"
TotalNew: "1"
TotalRefurbished: "0"
TotalUsed: "0"
__proto__: Object
Offers: Object
MoreOffersUrl: "http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B00I2ZBT1Y%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAI4JZRRS4PA7GCFZQ%26tag%3Dthegeepro-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3DB00I2ZBT1Y"
Offer: Object
OfferAttributes: Object
OfferListing: Object
Availability: "Usually ships in 1-2 business days"
AvailabilityAttributes: Object
IsEligibleForSuperSaverShipping: "0"
OfferListingId: "PVQjzvp2b6r3iZCPBIe4JMFyanPGPdoRu0Rx2acr66ZQD5H6hCtV2i9m6CjLgPcgNeEGfW1XHV6XiZjXvfWdloJrE6OOTY00wZe5xU7trPe6WMtl%2Ba%2Bk5A%3D%3D"
Price: Object
Amount: "0"
CurrencyCode: "USD"
FormattedPrice: "$0.00"
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
TotalOfferPages: "1"
TotalOffers: "1"
__proto__: Object
SmallImage: Object
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 0):

Leaving the question for posterity, but it seems to only be a problem with certain items. Every item I find for the search term "minecraft" comes up with 0 price, but everything else is fine. I don't understand it, but whatever.